# Content negotiation: how to remove JSON as a supported format?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm implementing a web service in ASP.NET Core 2.1 based on a specification that exclusively supports XML.  Therefore, the content negotiation process must return a XML document or respond with an error.  Unfortunately ASP.NET Core 2.1 supports JSON by default, and by default the content negotiation process always succeeds if a request is made with Accept: application/json.

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure an ASP.NET Core project so that the content negotiation process throws an error if any media type other than XML is set?

Comment: Note on duplicate -> accepted answer is for 1.0. Newer 2.x approach is in comments + other answers.

Comment: Doesnt look like the same question to me. That is about adding XML, not removing JSON.

Comment: When you say "exclusively supports XML" do you mean SOAP or HTTP with some custom XML response. For SOAP you should be looking at WCF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I mean disabling support for any encoding other than XML.  By default asp.net core 2.1 includes JSON as a supported output format, but some ad-hoc API specifications do not.  Thus to better implement these APIs then the content negotiation stage must reject any format other than the one that is actually supported.

Comment: @RAM I asked something else. If that XML is actually SOAP, don't use Web API or MVC. SOAP isn't just *SOAP*, it's an entire set of WS-* interoperability standards that are already implemented and handled by WCF.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the response document is XML but it is not SOAP.

Comment: Hello! Any luck on this please? I would like to reject anything other than XML in my .NET 2.1 web api!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I am late to the party. This works for me:

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(JsonOutputFormatter));
            options.InputFormatters.RemoveType(typeof(JsonInputFormatter));
            options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
        })
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your suggestion! I've just tested with a brand new project (dotnet new webapi) and your suggestion does work.  It also works with `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2`. Nevertheless, meanwhile I've noticed that using `AddMvc()` is counterproductive as it's just a wrapper over `AddMvcCore()` that adds a bunch of default options, such as JSON support.  Thus, if the end goal is to not support JSON then the best starting point is to not include it to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Use MVC input and output formatters:

```
services.AddMvc(configure =>
{
    // remove JSON formatter
    var outputFormatters = configure.OutputFormatters;
    var jsonOutputFormatter = outputFormatters.First(f => f is JsonOutputFormatter);
    outputFormatters.Remove(jsonOutputFormatter);
    var inputFormatters = configure.InputFormatters;
    var jsonInputFormatter = inputFormatters.First(f => f is JsonInputFormatter);
    inputFormatters.Remove(jsonInputFormatter);
}).AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
```

Comment: Thank you for posting an anwser.  However, your solution doesn't work.  I've tested your solution by sending a GET request with `Accept: application/json` and your solution returns a XML document with status code 200.  The expected response would be a status code 406 Not Acceptable or 415 Unsupported Media Type, accompanied with a blank body.

Comment: You can configure the formatter to not accept application/json, it accept */* by default I think, but I didn't check. Or write a middleware to check the accept header

Comment: Try with `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()` instead, I updated my answer and did a test (`curl -X GET "http://localhost:65134/api/v1/application" -H "accept: application/json"`), I received : `406 Error: Not Acceptable`

Comment: I've tried it but that does not work.  GET requests with `Accept:  application/json` return status code 200 OK with a JSON document in the request body.  That's actually the recommended way to add XML, which is featured in [Microsoft's own ASP.NET core 2.1 tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1), and they are very explicit in how it is used to add support for XML while keeping support for any other media type, including JSON.

Comment: @RAM the link you posted shows that you can use the `[Produces]` attribute to restrict the supported content types even [at the global level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the `[Produces]` keyword does set which format is used by a controller to produce a response, but it does not affect the content negotiation process.  If you add `[Produces("application/xml")]` to a controller, it generates XML with a status code of 200 OK in spite of whatever is passed in the `Accept` header.

Comment: @RAM there's probably an issue in your conf, I tested on my side and it works. Can you share your setup.cs and your .csproj

Comment: @aguafrommars I've created a fresh webapi project (dotnet new webapi) and replaced in Startup.cs `AddMvc()` with  `AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`.  That project returns status code 200 Ok no matter what is passed in the Accept header, and always returns JSON when the `Accept` header doesn't include `application/xml".  Adding `[Produces("application/xml")]`only forces the controller to output XML, but has no impact on the controller's content negotiation process.

Comment: @RAM did you remove JsonFormatter ?

Comment: @aguafrommars yes, I did.  I've created yet another fresh ASP.Net core 2.1 webapi project and not only removed the `JsonFormatter` but also added the XML serializer.  That has the exact same effect as adding `[Produces("application/xml")]`: the controller returns XML and status code 200 Ok no matter what's passed in the Accept header.

Comment: Well, you can write a middleware to check the accept header